# Calculating $G'(x)$ given $G(x) = \int_{-4}^{x^2} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to figure out what $G'(x)$ is, given

$$G(x) = \int_{-4}^{x^2} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt$$

This is what I have so far. Let

$$
\begin{align*}
F(x) &= \int_{-4}^x \frac{\sin t}{t} dt & \\
F'(x) &= \frac{\sin x}{x} &\qquad\text{Fundamental Theorem of Calculus} \\
G(x) &= F(x^2) & \\
G'(x) &= F'(x^2) & \\
&= \frac{dy}{dx}\left[ \left( \frac{\sin x}{x} \right)^2 \right] & \\
&= 2 \left(\frac{\sin x}{x} \right)\left( \frac{-\cos x \cdot x - \sin x}{x^2} \right)
\end{align*}
$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to think of it as a composition, and use the chain rule. I get $G'(x)=2x\,\dfrac{\sin\left(x^2\right)}{x^2},$ which you can simplify.

Comment: What you have is the derivative of $F(x)^2$, not $F(x^2)$.

Comment: I recommend you check this post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291235/calculating-gx-given-gx-int-4x2-frac-sin-tt-dt#comment6769469_3291235 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $G(x)$ can be written as $f(g(x))$, where
$$f(x)=\int_{-4}^x \frac{\sin t}{t}dt \quad \textrm{and} \quad g(x)=x^2$$
Now, by the FTC :
$$f'(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x} \quad \textrm{and} \quad g'(x)=2x$$
and by the Chain Rule, $G'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. That is
$$G'(x)=\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}\cdot 2x=\frac{2\sin(x^2)}{x} \quad \textrm{if } x\neq 0$$

Comment: You don't technically need the proviso of $x\not=0,$ since $x$ is still in the denominator of the result. You only need to display the proviso when a factor disappears from the denominator.

Comment: To be exact, $f'(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ when $x\neq 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$, which leads to $G'(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to think of it this way instead. Let $H(x) = x^2$. Then we have that $G(x) = F(H(x))$. Then you can directly apply the chain rule, which says that:
$$
G'(x)=F'(H(x))\cdot H'(x)
$$
You've already found $F'$, so you just need to plug the value $H(x)$ into $F'$ and then multiply by $H'$ (I leave this to you).

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the MVT for integrals:
$$G((x+h)^2)-G(x^2)=\int_{x^2}^{(x+h)^2} \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\mathrm{d}t =\frac{\sin(c)}{c} [(x+h)^2-x^2]$$
For some $c \in (x^2, (x+h)^2)$. And
$$\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h} \to 2x$$
Also
$$\frac{\sin(c)}{c} \to \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$$
As $h \to 0$, so the derivative is
$$\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}2x$$